# Nx Angular Workspace: How to share the index.html between multiple apps?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I currently have 3 apps in my nx workspace. All of these are Angular applications, so they all have an index.html file in the app-name/src folder. As these apps will all be deployed to the same domain by using different "url-subsets" they use to have the exact same index.html (meta tags, fav icon etc.)

It's obvious I don't want them to be redundant in each app, but rather have a shared index.html.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: You could try to change the path of the "index" property in the `angular.json`. So you have one `index.html` file in the root of your nx project and all apps have the index defined as "index.html" in the `angular.json`

Comment: Oh.. didn't know this was defined in angular.json..
I went with fileReplacements, but your Idea seems to be even simpler!

Comment: Does it matter if they aren't under the same domain (ie. somedomain.com and someotherdomain.com)? I'm looking at nx workspace to hold multiple Angular applications that share libs, components, pipes, theme, etc, but was hoping they could use the same index.html as well.  Originally we had these in separate modules in a single application, but they are now being split out so almost everything is the same, but we don't want specific modules loaded in specific domains now to prevent routing.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't matter. You can deploy every app in an NX workspace to a different domain, of course.

Comment: I would like to add, that the index.html won't be the same after compiling for both applications. Since they both bundle seperately from each other, both will have their own entry point. You should see, that after building both projects with the "shared" index.html, each dist folder will contain it's seperate entry point. So these modifications will only be relevant until the apps are compiled

Answer (score 0):

@Eweren's answer works!

starting the path to the lib with ./ like so:

```
"index": "./libs/name-of-lib/index.html"
```

I prefer @Eweren's answer, but yet there's another way to accomplish it by setting up fileReplacements for the index file in each project.